# Springboot application not fully start on an existing tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a working springboot application, build in java 1.8

I follow the springboot documentation to create a war, and deploy it in a Tomcat server.

I successfully started and tested the application in IntelliJ in local :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-08-13 14:44:07.801  INFO 10824 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] com.oaa.cos.web.Application         : Starting Application v0.0.33-SNAPSHOT on NBL000197 with PID 10824 (C:\Users\10067726\Documents\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\cosw\WEB-INF\classes started by 10067726 in C:\Users\10067726\Documents\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\bin)
2019-08-13 14:44:07.841  INFO 10824 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] com.oaa.cos.web.Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-13 14:44:14.017  INFO 10824 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5885 ms
13-Aug-2019 14:44:18.011 AVERTISSEMENT [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find Using deprecated META-INF/services mechanism with non-standard property: javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory. Property javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory should be used instead.
2019-08-13 14:44:26.385  INFO 10824 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-08-13 14:44:27.240  INFO 10824 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2019-08-13 14:44:27.687  INFO 10824 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] com.oaa.cos.web.Application         : Started Application in 23.395 seconds (JVM running for 49.022)
```

I want to deploy the war on an existing server, in an existing server instance, which already working for other war.

When a start the instance, it seems to stop before the end...

It never ends, and the application doesn't respond :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-08-13 14:53:34.993  INFO 11239 --- [           main] com.oaa.cos.web.Application         : Starting Application v0.0.33-SNAPSHT on dfrlmasoatc01.int.com with PID 11239 (/home1/tomcat9-multiharden/instances/default/webapps/EdgeCustomerOfferStorageWeb/WEB-INFclasses started by tomcat9 in /)
2019-08-13 14:53:35.005  INFO 11239 --- [           main] com.oaa.cos.web.Application         : No active profile set, falling backto default profiles: default
2019-08-13 14:53:36.659  INFO 11239 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialzation completed in 1591 ms
```

I already check these points :

- My application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
- I put the starter tomcat dependencies in provided
- The war is named "EdgeCustomerOfferStorageWeb.war", and the instance port is 10080, so I use : http://server:10080/EdgeCustomerOfferStorageWeb/
  It does not respond, it never ends loading. Servlet is 3.+, so no need of web.xml

How could I know what is going on after this step and why my application isn't really deployed ?
How can I access to the tomcat manager interface ?
Do you really think the application could be deployed and the incomplete logs could get me wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem.
Putting the log level in setenv.sh for my instance : 
-Dlogging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG

I see that the application wait on a specific bean creation.
In my case, this bean instanciate a soap client for a wsdl url.
The url was not correct, so the bean can't connect to it.

But there is one thing I don't understand : Why there is no default timeout or error from tomcat ? And why the other war in the same instance, which could be deployed before, can't work correctly ?
Tomcat block every application in the instance while one of them can't be deployed ?